# Disable onTouch until the activity is visible to the user

Tags: android, onclick, touch

I have two activity A and B, now in Activity A i have a button when i click on that button, i am preparing an object and moving to next screen for displaying the text view,image view etc etc.

Now in the Activity B i have some views with on Touch.

PROBLEM: if i click on the button multiple times in Activity A say twice or thrice then even before the Activiy B is being displayed the onTouch event on the texview will be triggered.

i have also made `setEnabled(false);` on the button so that once on the button is clicked.

How to solve this?

Comment: question is not clear enough :(

Comment: @StinePike what you didnt understand?

Comment: you are preparing and moving object to activity B? .. how the click on activity a's button trigger activity b's on touch? it would be helpful to see the code

Comment: no not the click but when you click on the button multiple times click happens only once but the ontouch is triggering and affecting the activity B's view even before the activity B is being displayed

Comment: @Goofy : If you don't post some code to help explain things, I expect this question will be closed.